# Может ли input иметь двойное имя

Tags: html5, input

Мне нужно, чтобы тег импут имел двойное имя, как класс, например:

```html
<input class="firstClass secondClass" type="radio" name="firstNane secondName" id="step1-5" value="Размер автомобиля: Джип">
```

Comment: А чем одно имя не угодило?

Comment: для каких таких целей вам такое нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандарт говорит следующее

> If the attribute is specified, its value must not be the empty string.
>   Any non-empty value for name is allowed, but the name `_charset_` is special:

что в переводе на русский звучит как

> Если атрибут указан, то его значением должна быть не пустая строка. Разрешено указывать любое непустое значение, кроме значения `_charset_`.

Поэтому фактически указать вы можете любую строку хоть с пробелом хоть нет. При отправке формы на сервер вы получите соответствующий ключ в массиве `$_POST` (для пхп). Но у вас не получится обращаться к этому элементу по как `firstName` или `lastName` отдельно, только все целиком.
В целом в js/jquery вы можете указать селектор как `$("input[name*='firstName']")`, но, честно сказать, смысла во всем этом особого не наблюдается.

Answer (score 0):

Можно передать в качестве массива

```
<input name="xd[]" value="firstName"/>
<input name="xd[]" value="lastName"/>
<input name="xd[]" value="testName"/>
```

Обработать

```
$_POST['xd'][0] == 'firstName'
$_POST['xd'][2] == 'testName'
```